# Windows 10 cannot change language after anniversary update

Tags: language, windows-10-v1607

I just received the Anniversary update on my computer at work (it's connected to a domain, though I have local administrator rights). Before the upgrade, the original Windows language was Dutch (it still is), but I changed the language for my account to English.

Now, I am unable to change my user language. I can add English as an input language, but when I go to settings for the language (in the new settings app) I cannot choose to download a language pack.

[image: language settings no display]

When I try to add the language pack from Control Panel, it says that no language pack is available.

[image: no language pack available]

The IT department insist that they're not blocking any of these settings.

I'm running Windows 10 Professional version 1607.14393.0

Any help in changing my language to English would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Starting a few days ago (about 2 weeks after originally posting this question), I couldn't cleanly shutdown my computer anymore. When I try to shut down or restart, it has to wait for some process. The description for this process is that it's working on downloading/installing a language pack. I'll make a picture the next time it happens.

Comment: 14383.0 is not the current build your missing updates.  Have your Domain Administrator uninstall the reinstall your language and keyboard layouts for you.  You do not have the permissions required to fix your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I do see new updates waiting for installation, I'll do that later to check if that helps. I'll ask the domain admin to do the install for me.